# Can we identify weak solutions of "restarted" parabolic PDEs?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open, $V:=H_0^1(\Omega)$, $H:=L^2(\Omega)$ and $a\in C^1([0,\infty)\times\overline\Omega)$ such that $\alpha:=\inf_{(0,\:\infty)\times\Omega)}a>0$. Moreover, let $$\mathfrak a_t(u,v):=\langle a(t)\nabla u,\nabla v\rangle_{L^2}\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in V$$ and $$\mathcal A(t):V\to V'\;,\;\;\;v\mapsto-\mathfrak a_t(\;\cdot\;,v)$$ for $t\ge0$. Let $u_0\in L^\infty(\Omega)$.

We say that $u$ is a weak solution of $$\left\{\begin{align}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}&=\nabla_x\cdot a\nabla_xu&\text{in }(0,\infty)\times\Omega\\u&=0&\text{on }(0,\infty)\times\partial\Omega\\u(0,\;\cdot\;)&=u_0\end{align}\right.\tag1$$ if $u\in L^2((0,T),H)$ has a weak derivative in $L^2((0,T),V')$ and $$\left\{\begin{align}u'&=\mathcal Au\\u(0)&=u_0\end{align}\right.\tag2$$ for all $T>0$.

> Now assume $t_0>0$ and $v$ is a weak solution of $(1)$ with $u_0$ replaced by $v_0:=u(t_0)$. Can we somehow identify $u$ and $v$?

We may note that, for all $T>0$, $u$ has a modification$^1$ $\tilde u\in C([0,T],V')$ and $$\tilde u(t)=\tilde u(s)+\int_s^tu'(r)\:{\rm d}r\tag3$$ for all $s,t\in[0,T]$.

---

$^1$ That is, $$\forall\varphi\in V:\langle\varphi,u(t)\rangle_H=\langle\varphi,\tilde u(t)\rangle_{V,\:V'}\tag4$$ for almost all $t\in(0,T)$.

Comment: @daw The question is, *which* identification would you suggest?

Comment: @daw Okay, if I'm not missing something, if $\varphi\in V$, we should have $$\forall t\ge t_0:\langle\varphi,u(t)-u(t_0)\rangle_H=\int_{t_0}^t\langle\varphi,u'\rangle_{V,\:V'}\\\forall t\ge0:\langle\varphi,v(t)-v(0)\rangle_H=\int_0^t\langle\varphi,v'\rangle_{V,\:V'}$$ and hence \begin{equation}\begin{split}\langle\varphi,v(t)-u(t)\rangle_H&=\langle\varphi,v(t_0)-u(t_0)\rangle_H+\underbrace{\int_{t_0}^t\langle\varphi,v'-u'\rangle_{V,\:V'}}_{=\:0}\\&=\langle\varphi,v(t_0)-u(t_0)\end{split}\end{equation} for all $t\ge t_0$. But how can we proceed from here?

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that $A$ depends on  $t$. Then again, why do you think that $u$ and $v$ agree? They satisfy $v(0)=u(t_0)$ but the differential equations are different.

Comment: @daw I don't think that they agree. My question is how they are related or, phrased differently, whether we can express $v$ in terms of $u$. That's what I've tried to establish in my comment above. Do you think we can built up on what I've shown there?